# Move the logout button of a shiny app that uses authentication

Tags: r, shiny, shinyauthr

I have a simple shiny app which uses authentication method. I would like to know if it is possible to move the "log-out" button from its current position inside the sidebar. The thing is that I want my sidebar to be hidden as well before the user logs in and I use  `req(credentials()$user_auth)` before it to do so. As a matter of fact the log-out button is not displayed at all. The username and password are "user1","pass1".

```
#app.r
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)
library(shinyjs)

# dataframe that holds usernames, passwords and other user data
user_base <- data.frame(
  user = c("user1", "user2"),
  password = c("pass1", "pass2"), 
  permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  row.names = NULL
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # must turn shinyjs on
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

  # add login panel UI function
  shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
  # setup table output to show user info after login
  sidebarLayout(
    uiOutput("menu"),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("user_table")
    )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # call the logout module with reactive trigger to hide/show
  logout_init <- callModule(shinyauthr::logout, 
                            id = "logout", 
                            active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth))

  # call login module supplying data frame, user and password cols
  # and reactive trigger
  credentials <- callModule(shinyauthr::login, 
                            id = "login", 
                            data = user_base,
                            user_col = user,
                            pwd_col = password,
                            log_out = reactive(logout_init()))

  # pulls out the user information returned from login module
  user_data <- reactive({credentials()$info})

  output$menu<-renderUI({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    sidebarPanel(
      # add logout button UI 
      div( shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout"))
    )

  })


  output$user_table <- renderTable({
    # use req to only render results when credentials()$user_auth is TRUE
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    user_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `pull-right` class and move UI into `sidebarPanel`

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # must turn shinyjs on
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  # add logout button UI 
  # add login panel UI function
  shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
  # setup table output to show user info after login
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(div(shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout"))), # UI moved here
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("user_table")
    )
  )

)
```

Comment: I have editted my question as your answer is good for non-reactive sidebar